# Activate Submit Button on Enter

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

Right now I have to click the `Login` button in order to send a form to the server.

I would like to press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key while on the password field.

This is the code:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="False" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
        <SCRIPT language="javascript" src="commonpages/js/Utility.js" type="text/javascript"></SCRIPT>
        <script>
        function GoBtn_ServerClick(oButton, oEvent) {
        }
        </script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:AliceBlue">
    <div id="main0">
    <!--<input id="auto" type=button value="Print test" onclick="Printtest();">-->
        <table width=800 align=center height=600px style="background-color:  AliceBlue;">
            <tr>
                <td width=25></td>
                <td width=750 align=center><form runat="server">
                <table ><tr><td colspan="2">
                </td></tr>
                <tr><td align=left>
                Login:</td><td align=right>
                <input id="login" runat=server type=text style="width: 100px"/></td>
                </tr><tr><td align=left>
                Password:</td><td align=right>
                <input id="pw" runat=server type=password style="width: 100px"/>
                </td></tr>
                <tr><td align=center colspan=2>
                <input type=button runat=server id=GoBtn value=Login style="width: 60" CausesValidation="False" />
                </td></tr></table></form>
                </td>
                <td width=25></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have searched Stack Overflow for similar questions, but they show examples of using ASP controls rather than HTML controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the 'type=button' to be 'type=submit' on your GoBtn, and it should get triggered when you press Enter.

Alternately, you could use jQuery to 'click' the button when the Enter key is pressed in the Password field:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#pw').keypress(function(e){
      if(e.keyCode==13)
      $('#GoBtn').click();
    });
});
```